# In a .NET Regex, combining zero-width positive look-ahead assertion with other search terms

Tags: .net, regex

I need to parse a file that has a multi-line header, any number of multi-line details, and a multi-line footer.  Each detail starts with a pattern, and the footer starts with a pattern.  Supposing that each detail starts with "detail", and the footer starts with "footer", I can successfully find each detail with: `(?s)detail.*?(?=(detail|footer))`, and what follows that is the next detail or the footer.

My problem is that I want one regex to find details that contain a particular word, and another regex to find details that don't contain that word.  That second regex isn't the problem, because I'm looping through the file, and if I don't find the first regex at the current offset, I try the second, so that second regex doesn't need to specify "and doesn't contain that word".

I know I could simply use `(?s)detail.*?(?=(detail|footer))`, and then see if that word is in that match, but I'm working with an existing framework that doesn't permit changing the logic.

What I've tried for that first regex has resulted in a match that includes multiple details until it finds one that contains that word.  I would instead need the match to fail if the word isn't found before the next "detail" or "footer".

For example, if the file contained:

```
header bla bla
bla bla
detail one bla
bla bla
detail two bla
bla bla SpecialWord bla
footer
bla bla
```

When ready to find the first detail, I'd like the first regex to fail, because there's no SpecialWord between the first "detail" and the second for the second to succeed, returning:

```
detail one bla
bla bla
```

However, my failed attempts have resulted in the regex matching:

```
detail one bla
bla bla
detail two bla
bla bla SpecialWord bla
```

How can I make a regex that starts with "detail", ends before the next "detail" or "footer", and has SpecialWord somewhere in there?  It would fail for the first detail in the example (because SpecialWord isn't between the first "detail" and the second), and would succeed for the second detail (because SpecialWord is between the second "detail" and "footer".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include an example of the input text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match the line starting with detail. Then continue matching all lines that do not either start with detail or footer or contain SpecialWord.

Then match the line that does contain SpecialWord, followed by the rest of the lines that do not start with either detail or footer.

```
^detail\b.*(?:\r?\n(?!detail\b|footer\b|.*\bSpecialWord\b).*)*\r?\n.*\bSpecialWord\b.*(?:\r?\n(?!detail\b|footer\b).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of line
- `detail\b.*` Match detail and the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n(?!detail\b|footer\b|.*\bSpecialWord\b).*` Match the line if not start with detail of footer or contains SpecialWord
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times to match all those lines
- `\r?\n.*\bSpecialWord\b.*` Match the line that contains SpecialWord
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n(?!detail\b|footer\b).*` Match the line if not start with detail or footer
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times to match all those lines

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5edetail%5cb.*%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!detail%5cb%7cfooter%5cb%7c.*%5cbSpecialWord%5cb%29.*%29*%5cr%3f%5cn.*%5cbSpecialWord%5cb.*%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!detail%5cb%7cfooter%5cb%29.*%29*&i=header+bla+bla%0d%0abla+bla%0d%0adetail+one+bla%0d%0abla+bla%0d%0adetail+two+bla%0d%0abla+bla+SpecialWord+bla%0d%0afooter%0d%0abla+bla%0d%0a%0d%0aheader+bla+bla%0d%0abla+bla%0d%0adetail+one+bla%0d%0abla+bla%0d%0adetail+two+bla%0d%0abla+bla+SpecialWord+bla%0d%0amore+text%0d%0afooter%0d%0abla+bla%0d%0a%0d%0aheader+bla+bla%0d%0abla+bla%0d%0adetail+one+bla%0d%0abla+bla%0d%0adetail+two+bla%0d%0abla+bla+SpecialWord+bla%0d%0amore+text%0d%0adetail%0d%0abla+bla%0d%0adetail%0d%0atest%0d%0aSpecialWord%0d%0adetail&o=m)