# Regex for "but does not contain"

Tags: .net, regex

In .NET, I need a Regex to find one string but not another.  Consider this text to search, with the bolded part what I'm trying to find:

aabb***aabbccbb***aabbdd

What I want to find is: text that starts with aa, ends before the next occurrence of either aa or dd, and contains cc.  I thought the solution would be aa(?!aa).*?cc.*?(?=(aa|dd)), but that selects aabbaabbccbb, but I don't want to include that initial aabb.  Obviously, for my real task, I'm not really searching for such pairs of letters, so I don't want to use searching for individual characters. What will find what I need?  Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

In bold is what I'd want to find, given a different search string:

***aaxyzccabcd***aawhatever***aablablaccblabla***dd

The search rule I need is: find text that starts with aa, ends before the next aa or dd (whichever comes first), and contains cc.

Comment: is the string alway a sequence of  the same letters

Comment: (?!^aa)\w*
prevents the "aa" at the start of the string from matching

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/FubE3D/1) what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question differently, and got a working answer, which can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63169037/1250500.  The solution involves two zero-width negative lookahead assertions, each within a non-capturing group.  Very impressive, and I'm glad it didn't require balancing groups.